# Determinant Expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How I will be able to found any expression for the determinant of the matrix $R^{N\times N}$ wiht entries belong $\mathbb{R} $, if $R_{ij}=\dfrac{2}{N}-\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $N$ is the size of the matrix, if it is not, the solution can be adapted easily.

Your matrix is

$$R= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{N}-1 & \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ..&\frac{2}{N} \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N}-1 & \frac{2}{N} & ..&\frac{2}{N} \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N}-1 & ..&\frac{2}{N} \\
...&...&...&...&... \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ..&\frac{2}{N}-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here is a simple solution if you know eigenvaleues. $R+I$ has rank $1$, which means that $\lambda=-1$ is eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $n-1$.

Also, the columns of $R-I$ add to $0$, thus $\lambda=1$ is also an eigenvalue of $R$.

Thus

$$\det(R)=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot 1 \,.$$

---

If you don't  know eigenvalues, add all rows to first one to get

$$\det(R)= \det \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & ..&1 \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N}-1 & \frac{2}{N} & ..&\frac{2}{N} \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N}-1 & ..&\frac{2}{N} \\
...&...&...&...&... \\
\frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & \frac{2}{N} & ..&\frac{2}{N}-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

now subtract $\frac{2}{N}$ times first row from all other rows to get:

$$\det(R)= \det \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & ..&1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & ..&0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & ..&0 \\
...&...&...&...&... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ..&-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=(-1)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Dear @N.S. and in the case $R'_{ij}=(-1)^{\delta_{jx_0}}(R_{ij}-\lambda \delta_{ij})$?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix such as your $R$ has a lot of structure that is worth understanding. Note this. Define the following, normalized vector

$$ |\xi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=1}^{N} |j\rangle$$

In other words $ |\xi\rangle$ is the unit vector with all components one in the standard basis ($|j\rangle$ is the vector with component $1$ at position $j$). Now note your matrix is simply

$$R = 2 |\xi\rangle \langle \xi| -I $$

were $I$ is the identity matrix. It should be clear that $|\xi\rangle \langle \xi|$ is the orthogonal projector projecting onto direction $|\xi\rangle$. Its eigenvalues hence are 1, with multiplicity 1, with eigenvector $|\xi\rangle$ and zero, with multiplicity $N-1$ corresponding to all vectors orthogonal to $|\xi\rangle$. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues hence

$$\det(R) = (2\cdot 1 -1) (2\cdot 0 -1)^{N-1} = (-1)^{N-1} $$

Comment: Thanks by your response, I am trying simply the next exercise, but same I think that the exercise that I posted not help me. I want find the characteristic polynomial for the Grover quantum operator 

$$\begin{align*}
(2|D\rangle\langle D| -I_N)(2|M^{\perp}\rangle\langle M^{\perp}| -I)
\end{align*}$$ 

where 
$|D\rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^{N} |i\rangle$ and $|M\rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N-m}}\sum_{i\notin M} |i\rangle$
and 
M is a vector space generated by the marked elements.

Comment: @juaninf I don't quite understand what's your $M$ and $|M\rangle$. And in particular  what is $|M^{\perp}\rangle$? Is it also a (normalized) vector?

Comment: yes is a normalized vector and $|i\rangle$ is a computational basis

Comment: @juaninf Anyway, let's assume $|M^{\perp}\rangle$ is just another normalized vector. You can see that your matrix (say $R$) maps the subspace generated by $|D\rangle$ and  $|M^{\perp}\rangle$ into itself. In this subspace it acts as a $2\times 2$ matrix of which you can easily find the eigenvalues. On the orthogonal space it acts as the identity (hence eigenvalue $1$). Is it clear?

Comment: when you say $R$ refer $R$ that I posted?

Comment: Well, I meant the matrix in the comment (you may want to give it a name). PS if you include "@username" I think I get notified of your comments otherwise they may go unnoticed.

Comment: ok, $R=(2|D\rangle\langle D| -I_N)(2|M^{\perp}\rangle\langle M^{\perp}| -I)$ is posible get the characteristic polynomial of $R$ without know the eigenvalues?

Comment: Hmm they are almost the same thing so "no". But the procedure I outlined allows you to find the characteristic polynomial. If it's not clear you can post another question (I'm getting the message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments..." :) ).

Comment: ok, thank now I will post this question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403418/determinant-expression-for-grover-operator